# How to re-appear on the other side of the map, Javascript

Tags: javascript

im creating a Asteroids game in Javascript, but I need some help. Let me try to explain what i mean, when the ship flies out on the right side of the map, how do i make him re-appear on the left side of the map?

Comment: Use modulus to truncate values higher than your map width. shipX = shipX % width;

Comment: Can you show us your current code and what you have tried so far?

Comment: `Map.goToTheOtherSide()` If that doesn't help, it's probably because we don't know how your game works and you need to give us details to work with.

Comment: This might be one of my favorite StackOverflow question titles, ever.

Answer (score 0):

The following demo shows how the ship that goes off the edge of the screen can be made to re-appear on the other side of the screen.

```js
const ship = document.querySelector('#ship');
const screenWidth = 300, screenHeight = 200;
let x = screenWidth / 2, y = screenHeight / 2;
let thrustersOn = false;
let rot = 0;

const moveAndDrawShip = () => {
  if (thrustersOn) { // move forward if thrusters on
    x += Math.cos(rot / 180 * Math.PI) * 5; // recalculate coordinates
    y += Math.sin(rot / 180 * Math.PI) * 5;
    if (x < 0           ) x += screenWidth;  // offscreen left
    if (x > screenWidth ) x -= screenWidth;  // offscreen right
    if (y < 0           ) y += screenHeight; // offscreen top
    if (y > screenHeight) y -= screenHeight; // offscreen bottom
  }
  // move the ship, both position and rotation
  ship.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ") rotate(" + rot + ")");
};

window.addEventListener('keydown', evt => {
  switch (String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode)) {
    case "J": rot -= 10; thrustersOn = false; break;
    case "K":            thrustersOn = true ; break;
    case "L": rot += 10; thrustersOn = false; break;
  }
});
window.addEventListener('keyup', evt => { thrustersOn = false; });

window.setInterval(moveAndDrawShip, 30);
```

```html
<div>Click the image first. Then press J, K, L to move/spin.</div><svg width="300" height="200">
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none">
    <rect id="border" x="10" y="10" width="280" height="180"></rect>
    <polygon id="ship" transform="translate(150,100) rotate(45)" points="-5,5 -5,-5 10,0"></polygon>
  </g>
</svg>
```